# Getting only one element of the array and its children

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an multidimensional array `categories` and I am looping over this array with `menuToElement` function.

It takes al the elements of the `array` and its children and returns it in a `ul`. the code is fully working, **but what I can't figure out is how to loop over only one element of the array and all its children.**

What I want to do is for example only loop over the engine element and all its children and all the children arrays. My question is: Is this even possible with the `for...of` loop that I am using, because I tried looping over the index of categories and it says it is not iterable.

```js
function menuToElement(menu) {
  const ul = document.createElement("ul");
  for (const item of menu) {
    const li = document.createElement("li");
    if (Object(item) === item) {
      li.textContent = item.text + ' \u25BD';
      li.appendChild(menuToElement(item.children));
    } else {
      li.textContent = item;
    }
    ul.appendChild(li);
  }
  return ul;
}

var categories = [{
  text: "engine",
  children: [1, 2, 3, {
    text: "piston",
    children: [4, 5, 6, {
      text: "piston",
      children: [4, 5, 6]
    }]
  }]
}, {
  text: "tire",
  children: [7, 8, 9]
}];
const ul = menuToElement(categories);
document.getElementById("menu").appendChild(ul);
```

```css
li>ul {
  display: none;
}

li:hover>ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu"></div>
```

Comment: Sounds like filter() should help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: Please also show your non-working code.

Comment: What I was trying that wasn't working was changing const ul = menuToElement(categories); to const ul = menuToElement(categories[0]);

Comment: you want to change your interface from menuToElement(Array) to menuToElement(Object)?

Comment: yes I think that is what I want

Comment: If I understand what you want correctly, you should be able to use mostly the same code. You just need to loop over `menu.children` instead of just `menu`, and remember to explicitly add in `menu.text` as an item before (or after) the loop.

Answer (score 0):

First we start with some helpers that make our life easier: `elem` and `text` -

```js
const elem = (tag, ...children) =>
{ const node = document.createElement(tag)
  children.forEach(node.appendChild.bind(node))
  return node
}

const text =
  document.createTextNode.bind(document)

const doc =
  elem
    ( "article"                    // <article>
    , elem("p", text("wash hand")) //   <p>wash hand</p>
    , elem("p", text("read book")) //   <p>read book</p>
    , elem("p", text("stay safe")) //   <p>stay safe</p>
    )                              // </article>

document.body.appendChild(doc)
```

```css
article { border: 1px solid tomato; }
p { border: 1px solid dodgerblue; }
```

Next we define how to convert *one* menu item to a menu node, `toMenu1` -

1. if the input `item` is an object, return a `LI` with `item.text` and call `toMenu` on `item.children`
2. otherwise (by induction) the input `item` is *not* an object. In this case, simply return an `LI` with plain text

```js
const toMenu1 = (item = {}) =>
  Object(item) === item
    ? elem('li', text(`${item.text} \u25BD`), toMenu(item.children)) // 1
    : elem('li', text(item))                                         // 2
```

We haven't written `toMenu` yet, but above we see that it expects an array of items. Writing this function is even easier than the last -

1. Return a `UL` where each item is converted using `toMenu1`

```js
const toMenu = (all = []) =>
  elem('ul', ...all.map(toMenu1)) // 1
```

Before we continue, expand the snippet below to verify the results in your own browser -

```js
const elem = (tag, ...children) =>
{ const node = document.createElement(tag)
  children.forEach(node.appendChild.bind(node))
  return node
}

const text =
  document.createTextNode.bind(document)

const toMenu1 = (item = {}) =>
  Object(item) === item
    ? elem('li', text(`${item.text} \u25BD`), toMenu(item.children))
    : elem('li', text(item))
    
const toMenu = (all = []) =>
  elem('ul', ...all.map(toMenu1))

var categories = [{
  text: "engine",
  children: [1, 2, 3, {
    text: "piston",
    children: [4, 5, 6, {
      text: "piston",
      children: [4, 5, 6]
    }]
  }]
}, {
  text: "tire",
  children: [7, 8, 9]
}];

const ul = toMenu(categories)
document.getElementById("menu").appendChild(ul)
```

```css
li>ul {
  display: none;
}

li:hover>ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu"></div>
```

---

**Now to answer your specific question:** Can we build a recursive menu using just *one* input item?

You can do this one of two ways. 1) By grabbing just the item you care about -

```js
const ul = toMenu([ categories[0] ]) // just the first category
// <ul>
//   <li>engine<ul>...</ul></li>
// </ul>
```

Or 2) By using `Array.prototype.filter` -

```js
const ul = toMenu(categories.filter(c => c.text === "engine"))
// <ul>
//   <li>engine<ul>...</ul></li>
// </ul>
```

---

**Bonus:** the special relationship between `toMenu1` and `toMenu` is known as [mutual recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_recursion). `toMenu1` calls `toMenu`, which calls `toMenu1`, which calls `toMenu`, and so on...

Answer (score -2):

To do that you need to use

```
Array.from()
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from

so it is used to convert DOM node (or children)
please if you want more explaining comment

Comment: @1-14x0r This is not a comment. It's an answer.